# What is a "reference conductor"?

Tags: simulation, cables

I am working with a twisted cable model.
Therefore I have:

- 2 input pins
- 2 output pins

But I also have a fifth input/output call "reference conductor". Based on the notation, it seems to be an input. But what is it?

Here is the model code VHDL-AMS of the compenent that I want to use.

```
Entity PVC Is 
  Generic (Constant length : Real;           -- line length in meters 
           Constant temp   : Integer := 0);  -- temperature parameter 
  Port (Terminal A1, A2 : Electrical;        -- input ports 
        Terminal B1, B2 : Electrical;        -- output ports 
        Terminal A0     : Electrical);       -- reference conductor 
End Entity PVC;
```

The rest in encripted.

Comment: Deviations from reality used in simulations are often inherently tied to the simulator used, so you might want to tell a bit more about your environment. My current guess out of anything would  be GND

Answer (score 1):

I'ld expect the voltage of the terminals to defined as the voltage difference with the reference.
The reference can be your circuit ground, but that is not a requirement.

I expect the model to model a delay of a signal of cable with a given length while taking into account the typical influence of temperature on this speed for a PVC protected twisted pair.